# Browser helper object is not working?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho, ieaddon

I want to create one division above website in which I have to show login button. In order to

achieve this I have made BHO program.

I have done my BHO(Browser Helper Object) code using C#. In that program I have given some

message box for the sake of testing. This BHO Im able to register /unregister with internet

explorer with no issues.

My problem is no messagebox is coming while website opening or navigating. And its shocking

its coming in widows explorer like when I open My computer , open a particular drive or

folder. Im completely stuck please help.

Im following

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350432/BHO-Development-using-managed-code

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149258/Inject-HTML-and-JavaScript-into-an-existing-page-w

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19971/How-to-attach-to-Browser-Helper-Object-BHO-with-C

Comment: @pinker I don't think so my code will applicable to you. Instead my suggestion is you develop 64bit architecture BHO.

Answer (score 0):

If your BHO is injected in Explorer, look in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects
```

and delete any references to the CLSID of your BHO.

we can't help you debugging your BHO problem in Internet Explorer if you dont't give us more infos.

Give OS version, bitness, IE version, bitness, and Development platform.

Check that your BHO is Enabled in Internet Explorer. See 
[Manage add-ons in Internet Explorer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/manage-add-ons#ie=ie-11)

Check if your DLL is loaded with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: I am using windows7 professional for now.


And my IE version is 10.0.9200.16540. 


yaah I've checked registery at 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects.

I have build x64 dll .


My extension is 64bit and I have developed in .net framework 3.5 .

Would this be compatible with IE 7, 8 , 9 10 browser ?

Comment: I have solved the issue. I had developed 64 bit bho extenssion although it require only 32 bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. I had developed 64 bit bho extenssion although it require only 32 bit. :)

Comment: Hello Anuj, May I know what code change you have done?

I am facing similar kind of issue, I have created one BHO which is running fine with my machine but for other few machines it is not working. 

I am not able to detect the reason why it is not working. I have 32 bit machine (working fine). I have checked in one 64 bit machine where it is working fine and in 3rd System, it is not working. it does not show any message box. So I am not able to detect the problem as well.